# How to make the canvas opaque where the root window is transparent?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Create a root window as transparent and I need my canvas to be opaque.

```
import tkinter as tk
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x750")
root.wait_visibility(root)
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.7)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, bg="black")
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't support what you want to do.

Comment: so is there any other library in python you would suggest that could support the above scenario?

Comment: Well you can work around it by having `<tkinter.Tk>` with alpha value of 0.7 and another window (`<tkinter.Toplevel>`) with the canvas over it. It will take a lot of work but it should work.

Comment: You cannot achieve this with tkinter, though the solution below is a good hacky way around it. I am not sure about other libraries, but take a look at PyQt and Kivy, I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

This code only works on Windows.

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Create the main root
main_root = tk.Tk()
main_root.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)
# Add a dummy Canvas that the real one will follow
dummy_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_root, width=200, height=200)
dummy_canvas.pack()

# Update the main event loop so that the window appears on the screen.
# If it is not there there will be an annoying glitch.
main_root.update()

# Create the second root that will go over the main one
second_root = tk.Toplevel(main_root)
# Make sure it doesn't have a title bar
second_root.overrideredirect(True)
# Create the real canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(second_root, width=200, height=200, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

def dragging(event=None):
    # Make the second_root go over where the dummy canvas is
    second_root.geometry("+%i+%i" % (dummy_canvas.winfo_rootx(), dummy_canvas.winfo_rooty()))
    # Lift it above the main root
    second_root.lift()

dragging()

# Bind it so that the second root aways follows the main one
main_root.bind("<Configure>", dragging)
main_root.mainloop()
```

It spawns a `Toplevel` over where the empty space is. It also detects when the main window is moved and moves to that location.

Comment: Changed the code so that it works better and added comments to explain how it works

Comment: Just to avoid later confusions, `main_root.update()` is not updating the main_root, but its updating the main event loop, I think saying `dummy_canvas.update()` has the same effect.

Comment: Yes I will add that to my answer